# Select rows based on distinct values of nested field in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery which looks like this:

[image: data]

The `sequence` field is a repeated `RECORD`. I want to select **one row per `stepName`** but if there are multiple rows per step name, I want to choose the one where `sequence.step.elapsedSeconds` and `sequence.step.elapsedMinutes` are not null, otherwise select the rows where these columns are null.

As shown in the image above, I want to select row no. 2, 4 and 5. I have calculated `ROW_NUMBER` like this: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY step.stepName) AS RowNum`.

Here´s my query so far in trying to filter out the unwanted rows:

```
WITH DistinctRows AS
(
select timestamp, 
  ARRAY (
    SELECT 
      STRUCT(
        STRUCT(
          step.elapsedSeconds, 
          step.elapsedMinutes, 
        ) as step
      ) 
    FROM 
      UNNEST(source_table.sequence) AS sequence
  ) AS sequence, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY step.stepName) AS RowNum
from source_table,
unnest(sequence) as previousCalls
order by timestamp asc
)

    SELECT *
    FROM DistinctRows,
    unnest(sequence) as sequence
    where (rowNum = 1 and (step.elapsedSeconds is null and step.elapsedMinutes is null)
    or (RowNum > 1 and step.elapsedSeconds is not null and step.elapsedSeconds is not null)
    order by timestamp asc
```

I need help in figuring out how to filter out the rows like no. 1 and 3 and would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused.  What does a *row* look like?  Is `stepname` part of sequence?

Comment: Also, can you have more than one stepN that is not null? Do you want all of them or just the largest in terms of seconds or sth.?

Comment: Can you show us the original table? You're showing us the result of your lateral join and I have a feeling that is not needed :)

Comment: I have updated the query with @GordonLinoff, @Martin Weitzmann. 
`stepName` is the subfield of `sequence` which is a repeated record. 
I would like to have only one row per `stepName`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Assuming that `stepname` is not part of the repeated column:

```
SELECT dr.* EXCEPT (sequence),
       (SELECT seq
        FROM unnest(dr.sequence) seq
        ORDER BY seq.step.elapsedSeconds DESC NULLS LAST, 
                 sequence.step.elapsedMinutes DESC NULLS LAST
       ) as sequence
FROM DistinctRows dr
ORDER BY timestamp asc;
```

If `stepname` is part of `sequence`, then the subquery would reaggregate:

```
SELECT dr.* EXCEPT (sequence),
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(sequence ORDER BY stepName)
        FROM (SELECT seq,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq.stepName
                                        ORDER BY seq.step.elapsedSeconds DESC NULLS LAST,  sequence.step.elapsedMinutes DESC NULLS
                                       ) as seqnum
              FROM unnest(dr.sequence) seq
             ) s
        WHERE seqnum = 1
       ) as sequence
FROM DistinctRows dr
ORDER BY timestamp asc
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gordon Linoff. `sequence` is a repeated record and therefore I am getting `The argument to ARRAY_AGG must not be an array type but was ARRAY<STRUCT<step STRUCT<elapsedSeconds STRING, elapsedMinutes ARRAY<STRING>>>`